# awk split field format

Tags: awk

```
awk '{split($2,a,"-")};
     {if ($1=="aa") {print "'$var'/"$1"/"a[1]"/"$2" '$var'/bb/"a[1]} 
      else {print "'$var'/"$1"/"a[1]"/"$2" '$var'/aa/"a[1]}}'
```

hi,
$2 is all lower case text. I have split it and would like to output a[1] in upper case.

How can I do this ?

Tom

Comment: You have been in Stack Overflow for five months, asked six question, never accepted an answer, never voted and never answered a question. See my comment bellow

Comment: Good grief. Sorreeee. Ummmmm.... You're right. I've taken too much for granted. It's conceivable that I could help someone so I will at least think about it. I can vote when I see a good answer (...but wait I don't have enough reputation to do this!).Certainly, I can vote on answers to questions I have posed as well. A minimum, I agree. Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use awk's `toupper(a[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid complex and hard to read quoting if you use AWK's variable passing. You can also make use of the Output Field Separator. Also, you have extra curly braces that you don't need.

```
awk -v "var=$var" 'BEGIN{OFS="/"}
  {split($2,a,"-"); a[1]=toupper(a[1])
  if ($1=="aa") {print var, $1, a[1], $2 " " var, "bb", a[1]} 
    else {print var, $1, a[1], $2 " " var, "aa", a[1]}}'
```

Comment: Thank you Dennis - your answers are my first port-o-call when I lurk in these forums.

Comment: As a matter of passing interest, the condition $1=aa actually fails. My guess it's because of the ambiguity of the input. $1 ~ /^aa/ , on the other hand, appears to function as hoped.  Tom